# Why my ajax request doesn't get compiled?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

This part of my code isn't working, I already tried to do everything but it still doesn't working, what can I do to fix it?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://corona-api.com/countries/BR",
    type: "GET",
    sucess: function(response){
        document.getElementById("ifbr").innerHTML = response.latest_data.confirmed
    },
    error: function(){
        document.getElementById("ifbr").innerHTML = "Erro na Consulta !"
    }
})
```

Comment: `sucess` -> `success`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change `sucess` into `success`, and add `data` like below:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://corona-api.com/countries/BR",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response){
        document.getElementById("ifbr").innerHTML = response.data.latest_data.confirmed
    },
    error: function(){
        document.getElementById("ifbr").innerHTML = "Erro na Consulta !"
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Confirmed: <span id="ifbr"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled `success` here

```
sucess: function(response)
```

Instead it should be

```
success: function(response)
```

Comment: Thanks hahah i have been facing the code for a while and I didn't realize that!